# Replacing a specific bit of text in all php files on a server?

Tags: php, text, replace

So I just got my sorry ass hacked, the hack put some obscure string in *almost* every one of the php files on my website. How can I remove every instance that line occurs?

The code it added started with `<?php` so therefore I cannot simply replace it with blank, I need to delete it and move up the actual relevant code up one line as `<?php` cannot start on a white space...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your favourite IDE probably already have a find/replace in files/project function. If not try [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) Press Ctrl-Shift-F to open the Find in Files dialog where you can specify the root folder, a *.php file filter and then use either the regular expression option or extended code option to zap the unwanted code. If you post a sample of a hacked file we might be able to help you with the exact string to specify.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
find ./ -type f -name *.php -exec sed -i 's/stringtofind/stringtoreplacewith/g' {} \;
```

or this:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/stringtofind/stringtoreplacewith/g' `grep -ril stringtofind *`
```